# Can I be doxxed on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, security

[Doxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxing) is "the Internet-based practice of researching and broadcasting personally identifiable information about an individual."

Assuming I haven't posted anything about my identity, can I be doxxed on Stack Exchange?  Does the site provide my IP address or other identifying information to privileged users or moderators of the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should peruse the [Stack Exchange Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), which applies to every site in the network.

In a nutshell:  **don't post anything that could publicly identify you if that makes you feel uncomfortable.**  The likelihood of moderators abusing their power and identifying you is slim.

In a few broad strokes:

- Stack Exchange collects information about you, but doesn't use that to identify you.

  > When you use the network, we also collect potentially personally identifying information in the form of Internet Protocol (IP) addresses. But we don’t use that information to identify you, and we handle and disclose these addresses in the same way we handle other potentially personally identifying information as described below.
- If you post personal information in public, it's public.

  > Some users may elect to publicly post personally identifying or sensitive information about themselves in their normal use of the network. This could occur through use of the optional profile fields, in question or answer posts, or when an individual posts a job history on the Careers site. Information like that, which is voluntarily posted in publicly visible parts of the network, is considered to be public, even if it would otherwise be considered to be personally identifying or sensitive. As such, it is not subject to the protocols listed below, because we don’t control it; you do. Additionally, voluntarily publicizing such information means that you lose any privacy rights you might normally have with regards to that information. It also increases your chances of receiving unwanted communications, like spam.
- *Generally*, the site will tell you how they're using your data.

  > When we collect your personal information, we’ll tell you how we’re using it, any types of third parties to which we might disclose it, (other than moderators or “agents,” such as vendors or contractors, who are only processing such information for us or at our direction), and the choices we offer you to limit the use of your information.

Comment: You should stick in there a bit about how access to PII by mods (and presumably employees) is logged.